# Java Annotation Processor handle modified source code positions

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, local-variables, annotation-processing

I'm writing custom annotation processor and got struggling with code elements' positions.

Imagine I have the code:

```java
    public class DummyStepClass {

        @Step
        public void getInfo() throws Exception {
            HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
            @Remember("REQUEST") HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(new URI("https://postman-echo.com/get"))
                    .GET()
                    .build();
            @Remember("RESPONSE") HttpResponse<String> response = 
                    client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            System.out.println(response.statusCode());
            System.out.println(response.body());
        }
    }
```

Purpose of annotation is to save variable into context of a program flow through my steps.

**Context** class:

```java
    public class Context {

        private static final HashMap<String, Object> storage = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        private Context() {}

        public static void save(String k, Object v) {
            storage.put(k, v);
        }
    }
```

Literally I want to achieve invoking ***Context.save(k, v);*** when annotated rather than writing it  every time.

So as a result I want to have something like this:

```java
    public class DummyStepClass {

        @Step
        public void getInfo() throws Exception {
            HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(new URI("https://postman-echo.com/get"))
                    .GET()
                    .build();
            Context.save("REQUEST", request);
            HttpResponse<String> response =
                    client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            Context.save("RESPONSE", request);
            System.out.println(response.statusCode());
            System.out.println(response.body());
    }
}
```

I do generate this lines of code and they appears in **.class** files. However this two statements are added in the end of a method.

How can I handle this?

Comment: Manipulating the source code is not foreseen by the official annotation processing API at all. Officially, annotation processors can only add new classes. We can’t tell you, how to solve problems with your hack involving non-standard APIs when you don’t even show what you’ve done.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make this work by hooking into "blocks" of java code and pasting my code at the end.